# Shattering with sinusoids

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, harmonic-analysis, machine-learning

Let $d \geq 2$ and $K$ some positive integer. Consider distinct points $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_K\in \mathbb{T}^d$ and (not necessarily distinct) $z_1, \ldots, z_K \in \{-1,1\}$, does there exist an eigenfunction of the Laplacian $f: \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $sgn(f(\theta_i)) = z_i$ for all $i$?

Here sgn is signum function.

Inspired by this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307363/14414)

Comment: What happens when the dimension $d = 1$?

Comment: There is an obstruction similar to that mentioned by Robert Israel in the linked question, that either $f(x_1,\dots,x_d)=f(-x_1,\dots,-x_d)$ for all $x$ or $f(x_1,\dots,x_d)=-f(-x_1,\dots,-x_d)$ for all $x,$ identifying $\mathbb T$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb C.$ So there cannot be an odd number of negative signs among $f(0,\dots,0),f(i,\dots,i),f(-1,\dots,-1),f(-i,\dots,-i)$ for example.

Comment: @Dap can this be overcome by stating points not to lie on the boundary? How serious is this problem. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You could restrict the $\theta$'s by requiring $\theta_i\neq -\theta_j.$ (Or if you think of $\mathbb T$ as $\mathbb R/\mathbb 2\pi Z$ the condition would be $\theta_i\neq \theta_j+(\pi,\dots,\pi)$.)

Comment: Thanks @Dap . Looks like its not a problem

Comment: Crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323355/shattering-with-sinusoids

Answer (score 0):

I'll use $\mathbb T=\mathbb Z/2\pi\mathbb Z.$

For generic choices of $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_K$ there is an $n$ such that $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(n(\theta_i)_1))=z_i$ for $i=1,\dots,K.$ If we have the following irrationality condition in the first co-ordinate:

$$k_1(\theta_1)_1+\cdots+k_K(\theta_K)_1\neq 0\in\mathbb T^d\text{ for all non-zero }k\in\mathbb Z^d$$

then the sequence $(n(\theta_1)_1,\dots,n(\theta_K)_1)$ is dense in $\mathbb T^K$ - see for example [Exercise 5 here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/) for a much stronger quantitative result. The set of $t\in\mathbb T^K$ such that $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(t_i))=z_i$ for $i=1,\dots, K$ is an non-empty open set, so any dense set will intersect it.

On the other hand, for any $d$ there are counterexamples for special values of $K,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_K.$ The argument is basically by counting dimensions. Take $p$ to be a prime with

$$2^{d+3}<p< e^{p^d/8}.$$

Take $K=p^d$ and take $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_K$ to be an enumeration of $\{0,2\pi\tfrac1p,\dots,2\pi\tfrac{p-1}p\}^d=\{x\in\mathbb T^d\mid px=0\}.$

Every eigenfunction on $\mathbb T^d,$ when restricted to $\{x\mid px=0\},$ can be written in the form $f_{\lambda,A}(x)=\mathrm{Re}\sum A_k e^{k\cdot x},$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,$ and the sum is over $k\in(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^d$ satisfying $k_1^2+\dots+k_d^2=\lambda\pmod{p},$ and $A_k\in\mathbb C.$

There are $p$ different values of $\lambda.$ For each $\lambda$ there are at most $2^dp^{d-1}$ solutions of $k_1^2+\dots+k_d^2=\lambda\pmod{p}$ - at most $p^{d-1}$ choices of $k_1^2,\dots,k_d^2,$ then $2^d$ choices of square roots $k_1,\dots,k_d.$ This gives at most $2^{d+1}p^{d-1}\leq p^d/4$ real dimensions. Linear classifiers with $m$ real dimensions have VC dimension $m,$ so by Sauer-Shelah, functions of the form $f_{\lambda,A}$ (for fixed $\lambda$) can achieve at most

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor p^d/4\rfloor}\binom{p^d}{i}$$

vectors $(\operatorname{sgn}(f_{\lambda,A}(\theta_1),\dots,\operatorname{sgn}(f_{\lambda,A}(\theta_{p^d})))\in\{-1,1\}^{p^d}.$ By Hoeffding's inequality this is at most 
$e^{-p^d/8}2^{p^d}.$ By a union bound over the $p$ choices of $\lambda,$ there are at most $pe^{-p^d/8}2^{p^d}<2^{p^d}$ vectors achieved by any $f_{\lambda,A}.$ So there is some combination of signs that is not achieved by any eigenfunction.